# How to clear/pushthe "small" part of my H3 heading in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making use of the `<small>` tag within a heading tag in Bootstrap to deliver a sub message per section of my website. The code is simple:

```
<h3>This is my main part of the Heading 3 tag: <small>This is the small part of my h3 tag</small></h3>
```

I just think it looks rubbish when the browser is resized to a narrow width and the `<small>` content is wrapping. Is there anyway to make the small tag clear is starts to spill onto a second line?

[image: This is looking good when the browser is wide]

[image: Not so good when the width is reduced]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess this css should just about do what you want..

```
h3 small {
    display: block;
}
```

`small` is normally a `display: inline` inline element, so thats why it stays behind the text of your heading. Turning it into a block level elemment, it will automatically take 100% with and will start on a new line.

The css above will basically turn all the `<small>` tags within any `<h3>` into block elements.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However this will clear it even at full width. I was thinking more along the lines of Bootstrap responsiveness picking up when the browser width is reduced.

Comment: So do exactly the same thing, but add it to your appropriate screen size... ie. within `@media (max-width: 800px ) { ... }`